SPSS 23 - R Integration of function STATS_RELIMP does not work
I installed R 3.1.0 plus the R Essentials for SPSS 23 and wanted to use the STATS RELIMP function in SPSS 23. Unfortunately it does not work and I have no clue why.
Furthermore under EXTRAS I do not see STATS_RELIMP in the list of installed extensions and if I try to "download and install" an extension, there is an error message that the link to the IBM page is not correct.
Re-installed the R Essentials for SPSS 23.
Tried to install the package RELAIMPO in R3.1.0, but failed.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
